# Why Dimension applied to one table influences both JTables?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have 2 `JTable`s, both placed in their own `FastScrollPane`s, and them scroll pane placed into `JPanel` and then they both are placed into `JPanel`. I put different objects as the parameters in `.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dimensionPrameters)`, however, both tables tend to have the same size.

How I can make them fully independent on each other?

The code:

```
Dimension dimensionPayments = new Dimension(600, 60);

table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table1.getPreferredSize());
table2.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dimensionPayments);

FastScrollPane fastScrollPane1 = new FastScrollPane(table1);
fastScrollPane1.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

FastScrollPane fastScrollPane2 = new FastScrollPane(table2);
fastScrollPane2.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

firstPanel.add(fastScrollPane1);
firstPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

secondPanel.add(fastScrollPane2);
secondPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

allPanel.add(firstPanel);
allPanel.add(secondPanel);
```

[image]

In the image the effect I'm trying to avoid is encircled.

In order to get minmal reproducible example, please check the below code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.ParseException;


public class CfgTrafficProvidersBoxTest extends JPanel {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1500904348023955658L;

  private JTable changeTrafficProviderTable;
  private JTable changeTrafficProviderPaymentsTable;

  private final String PRICE_FORMAT = "#.####";

  public JButton addBtn;
  public JButton addPaymentBtn;
  public JButton saveBtn;
  public JLabel addTrafficProviderServiceLabel;
  public JLabel addTrafficProviderPaymentLabel;
  private long editId = -1;


  CfgTrafficProvidersBoxTest() {
    createGUIElements();
  }

  public void createGUIElements() {

    JPanel allAndSavePanel = new JPanel();
    allAndSavePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(allAndSavePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel allPanel = new JPanel();
    allPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
    firstPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    firstPanel.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    addTrafficProviderServiceLabel = new JLabel("Add Service");
    addTrafficProviderPaymentLabel = new JLabel("Add Payment");

    firstPanel.add(addTrafficProviderServiceLabel);
    allPanel.add(firstPanel);

    JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
    secondPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    changeTrafficProviderTable = new JTable();
    changeTrafficProviderTable.setModel(new TableModel()  {
      @Override
      public int getRowCount() {
        return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public int getColumnCount() {
        return 6;
      }

      @Override
      public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return "name"+columnIndex;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return "aa";
      }

      @Override
      public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

      }

      @Override
      public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {

      }

      @Override
      public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {

      }
    });

    JScrollPane fastScrollPane = new JScrollPane(changeTrafficProviderTable);
    fastScrollPane.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    secondPanel.add(fastScrollPane);
    secondPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(600, 20);
    Dimension dimensionPayments = new Dimension(600, 60);

    changeTrafficProviderTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dimension);

    addBtn = new JButton("X");
    addBtn.setAlignmentX(JComponent.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    secondPanel.add(addBtn);

    allPanel.add(secondPanel);

    saveBtn = new JButton("SAVE");
    changeTrafficProviderTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
    changeTrafficProviderTable.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);

    JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();
    thirdPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    thirdPanel.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    thirdPanel.add(addTrafficProviderPaymentLabel);
    allPanel.add(thirdPanel);

    JPanel forthPanel = new JPanel();
    forthPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(forthPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    changeTrafficProviderPaymentsTable = new JTable();
    changeTrafficProviderPaymentsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(dimensionPayments);
    changeTrafficProviderPaymentsTable.setModel(new TableModel()  {
      @Override
      public int getRowCount() {
        return 1;
      }

      @Override
      public int getColumnCount() {
        return 6;
      }

      @Override
      public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return "name"+columnIndex;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return String.class;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return "aa";
      }

      @Override
      public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

      }

      @Override
      public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {

      }

      @Override
      public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {

      }
    });

    JScrollPane fastScrollPanePayments = new JScrollPane(changeTrafficProviderPaymentsTable);
    fastScrollPanePayments.setAlignmentX(JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    fastScrollPanePayments.setVerticalScrollBar(fastScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar());
    forthPanel.add(fastScrollPanePayments);

    addPaymentBtn = new JButton("XX");
    addPaymentBtn.setAlignmentX(JComponent.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

    forthPanel.add(addPaymentBtn);
    allPanel.add(forthPanel);

    allAndSavePanel.add(allPanel);
    saveBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    Box b = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    b.add(saveBtn);
    b.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    allAndSavePanel.add(b);
    this.add(allAndSavePanel);
  }


  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new CfgTrafficProvidersBoxTest());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

and the image:

[image]

note

```
Dimension dimension = new Dimension(600, 20);
Dimension dimensionPayments = new Dimension(600, 60);
```

applied to both different tables

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3BFk.png
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be messing with the `preferredSize` of the `JScrollPane`, but would, instead, consider overriding the `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` of the `JTable`.  It's also likely an issue with the layout manager of `allPanel`, but we're missing a lot of context, it's also possible that `FastScrollPane` could be doing something, but since it's a non-standard component, that's just guess work

Comment: *How I can make them fully independent on each other?* - they should be unless the layout manager makes them the same size. We don't know what the layout manager of the "allPanel" is. Some comments: 1) Typically you set the layout manager BEFORE you add components to the panel.  2) Why are you creating a separate panel just to add the scroll pane to the panel? 3)  Why are you specifying the "secondPanel" as a parameter when creating the BoxLayout for the "firstPanel"? I've never seen a panel shared by multiple layout managers like this before. Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @camickr 2) is done for add + button, but this button is ommited from the sample code

Comment: Still waiting for the [mre]. Your question is about the size of two tables. So create a simple example with two table where each has its own size. Once that works then you add the other components. Simplify the logic so you understand how the layout managers work. Having a table and a horizontal button doesn't affect the vertical height.

Comment: @camickr let me prepare

Comment: @camickr I have prepared the example not depending on internal classes, just pure swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why the code implements TableModel. For a simple example it is one statement to create a TableModel. Just use

```
table.setModel( new DefaultTabelModel(1, 5) );
```

Also, no idea why you create a panel to hold each label. You stated in your comment you need a panel because the table has a button on the right. Well, the label doesn't have a button so there is no need for the panel. Keep the code simple. It is too hard to keep track of all then unnecessary panels that you have created.

> however, both tables tend to have the same size.

This is your basic code:

```
JPanel allPanel = new JPanel();
allPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

....
allPanel.add(firstPanel);

...
allPanel.add(secondPanel);

...
allPanel.add(thirdPanel);

...
allPanel.add(forthPanel);
```

The allPanel uses a GridLayout. The GridLayout will make all components the same size. So the size of each component will be the size of the largest table.

This is also why you have space between the labels and the tables.

Don't use a GridLayout. Instead use a vertical BoxLayout or a GridBagLayout.